# Using MySQLI how can I display data from my database on my website

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have long procrastinated switching to MySQLI from MySQL. I have started a new project and decided I'd rather go ahead and start it off with good habits instead of bad ones with deprecated MySQL.

I am trying to figure out how to iterate through a table in my database and display that data on my website. The process, I am sure, is straight forward but the explanation so you will understand the question is less so. I will try to be brief.

Example: I have a database named DATABASE that contains a table called TABLE. On my website I have 5 categories. Each category has a list of 5 items each. Each item in each list in turn has 5 values assigned to it. IE: name, dob, year, month, date. Those 5 values I have stored in my database for each list item in each category.

Visual Representation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIvhY.jpg (Each one of the list items has 5 values )

Code: [COLUMN_#] represents the column in the db table corresponding to the value I'd like to pull and insert into the page/html

```
<div class="category_1"> <!-- First loop iteration -->
    <div class="item_1"> 
        <a title="[COLUMN_1]" href="[COLUMN_2]">[COLUMN_3]</a>
        <span class="class">[COLUMN_4]</span>
        <span class="class"> [COLUMN_5]</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="category_1"> <!-- Second loop iteration -->
    <div class="item_2"> 
        <a title="[COLUMN_1]" href="[COLUMN_2]">[COLUMN_3]</a>
        <span class="class">[COLUMN_4]</span>
        <span class="class"> [COLUMN_5]</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="category_1"> <!-- Third loop iteration -->
    <div class="item_3"> 
        <a title="[COLUMN_1]" href="[COLUMN_2]">[COLUMN_3]</a>
        <span class="class">[COLUMN_4]</span>
        <span class="class"> [COLUMN_5]</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And so on to the 5th loop iteration for category 1. (one iteration for each list item.)

All the values for all list items from all 5 categories are in the same database so I assume if I wanted to pull the values into the page from the db for category 1 the code would need to be something like - select all from table where category is equal to 1 - I write a loop. Then when the loop finds no more list items with category equal to 1 it ends and moves on to the next script below that to query list items for category 2. And so on.

PHP Code so far:

```
<?php
// Connect to and select a database
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'DATABASE');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

// Query the table 'TABLES' (I'm also assuming I only need to query just the table from here)
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `TABLE`
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance this problem is really getting me and I don't want to go back to MySQL. Everyone here tells me not to! =)

Comment: Curious, if you're starting over, have you looked at [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead? It's much more robust and powerful.

Comment: I have I do plan on learning it but the site I'm doing now is for a client/friend who is familiar with MySQLI so if he needs to edit it down the road he'll be lost with PDO. Personally I'll be learning it. Just didn't want to build his site with MySQL.

Comment: Ah, makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big thing to remember in `mysqli` OOP is that when you get your `$result`, it too is an object. So you would perform operations with that instead

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['fieldname'];
}
```

Comment: You've shown me how to echo out all the values in a specific column, so thanks, but im still no where close to sure how to echo out all 5 values into the html in a loop and from ONLY values that have a category values of 1. EDIT: Tho I am much closer with this. Is  there a way to pull values from the database with this code with specific values?

Comment: So you just want to skip those loops?

Comment: One sec, I'm applying your code. May be very close to having it.

Comment: It worked. =) I'm not 100% done as I still need to be able to do this while making your code output only columns with specific values. That's another question though. I'll be asking it after this. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_first = 'mohamad';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($resultCheck > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo $row['user_uid'] . '<br>';
        }
    }
```

$conn = your data base connect code

Comment: You should add some explanation to answer.