# How to loop though data in the database while only querying columns with certain values?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

This is part of an issue that I had half of resolved in a previous question but this is another question entirely. 
My previous question to give you a basis for what I am trying to achieve:

[Using MySQLI how can I display data from my database on my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437202/using-mysqli-how-can-i-display-data-from-my-database-on-my-website)

NOTE: Column 17 in the table has a value of a number ranging 1-10. These are 10 different sets of information. With the code below I am only interested in query and displaying the results in the table that have the value of 1 in that specific column

How can I use the following code or modify it so that ONLY rows/items in the table that have a value of 1 (or w/e value i choose to run the script with) will be displayed as results when the loop iterates through.

IE: there are 5 columns one, two, three, four, and blooean. All the values in the boolean column are either true or false. I may only want to display results that have a true value. But instead used with my code below and have a vlue of 1.

My Code:

```
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo 
                    '<div class="list-item-container">'
                    . '<img class="favicon" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain='. $row['favicon_url'] . '" />'
                    . '<div class="list-item"><a title="' . $row['affiliate_name_title'] . '" href="' . $row['affiliate_url'] . '">' . $row['affiliate_name'] . '</a><span class="tld">' . $row['tld'] . '</span><span class="list-item-note"> ' . $row['country'] . '</span></div>'
                    . '<div class="unverified_icon"><img title="' . $row['verified_title'] . '" src="img/icons/' . $row['verified_image'] . '" /></div>'
                        . '<div class="hover-img"><a href="' . $row['games_url'] . '"><img class="games-icon" src="img/icons/games.png" alt="" title="' . $row['games_title'] . '"/></a><a href="' . $row['payments_url'] . '"><img class="payment-icon" src="img/icons/payment.png" alt="" title="' . $row['payment_title'] . '"/></a><img src="blank.gif" class="flag ' . $row['country_image'] . '" alt="Czech Republic" title="' . $row['flag_title'] . '"/></div>'
                    . '</div>';
                }
                ?>
```

As always, thanks!

EDIT: No one seems to understand what I mean. Sorry, not sure how else to explain/ask it.

I am running this same script in a lot of different locations on the same page.

On each location of the page I want to run the same script

Each place I run it I would like to be able to display only certain items from the table based on a option(not sure what its called) i give it. In div_1 i run the script and I need to display all results with a column 17 value of 1.

In div 2 I run the script but want to display only results/values from the table that have a column 17 value of 2, etc, etc,.

Comment: You really should be using `htmlspecialchars()` around arbitrary data used in the context of HTML.

Comment: But do you want a solution in PHP or SQL? If it is PHP then why?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you just said. =) @brad

Comment: Solution in either or. I don't mind.

Comment: @user2526699 instead of `echo row['somefield']`, use `echo htmlspecialchars(row['somefield'])`.  This will escape special HTML characters into their proper entities, ensuring you have valid HTML and no surprises when your data contains `<` or `>` or `&`, etc.  This also prevents against XSS attacks in certain circumstances.

Comment: If that's the case once I figure this out I will implement your suggestion. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do it in your query ahead, like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE value=1";
```

Or using your own code, it would be:

```
<?php
// Connect to and select a database
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'DATABASE');

 if($db->connect_errno > 0){
      die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
  }

  // Query the table 'TABLES' (I'm also assuming I only need to query just the table from here)
 $sql = <<<SQL
  SELECT *
  FROM `TABLE`
  WHERE `Column17` = 1
 SQL;

 if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
  }
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo 
                '<div class="list-item-container">'
                . '<img class="favicon" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain='. $row['favicon_url'] . '" />'
                . '<div class="list-item"><a title="' . $row['affiliate_name_title'] . '" href="' . $row['affiliate_url'] . '">' . $row['affiliate_name'] . '</a><span class="tld">' . $row['tld'] . '</span><span class="list-item-note"> ' . $row['country'] . '</span></div>'
                . '<div class="unverified_icon"><img title="' . $row['verified_title'] . '" src="img/icons/' . $row['verified_image'] . '" /></div>'
                    . '<div class="hover-img"><a href="' . $row['games_url'] . '"><img class="games-icon" src="img/icons/games.png" alt="" title="' . $row['games_title'] . '"/></a><a href="' . $row['payments_url'] . '"><img class="payment-icon" src="img/icons/payment.png" alt="" title="' . $row['payment_title'] . '"/></a><img src="blank.gif" class="flag ' . $row['country_image'] . '" alt="Czech Republic" title="' . $row['flag_title'] . '"/></div>'
                . '</div>';
            }
   ?>
```

Comment: I have multiple version of this script running on the same page. Each script runs and displays information in a div. Each script displays a different category in each div. It's the same script tho. I just need to be able to  display different results each time i run it on the page by specifying it to only pull data with a culmn equal to 'whatever'

Comment: You could then probably pass the column and the value of that coulmn to this script and it will just change accordingly. For example instead of column17 you want to test it with column16 and instead of 1 a value of 0.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean, sorry?

Comment: Using the code I wrote there has to be a way to call only the items in the table with a specific column value of my choosing?

Comment: I used it your way. Not exactly how I figured it needed it to work but to be honest it's the same thing so thanks! Accepted.

Comment: Glad that it work for you @user2526699. Happy coding and GOD bless. Sorry for not responding right away as I was away right after I made my answer.